# How do I **write** to ArraySegment<byte>.Array? Should I use unsafe code?

Tags: c#, arrays, unsafe

There are many questions that ask how to get a subset of an array on this site, however no one has successfully gotten an answer on how to write to the array as if it were `byte[]`.

```
byte[] bigTargetBytes = new byte[10000];

byte[] twentyBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(sourcebytes);  // size is 20 bytes, 
// how do I append this to the existing array without copying, using Linq, etc?
```

What I don't want to do is have two arrays and do a copy between them, since that is time intensive proportional to the length of the array (and my arrays are long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you want, but I'm guessing you want a "view" onto an array of bytes. In .Net 4.5, you can do this with `ArraySegment<T>`:

```
var a = new byte[100];
var s = new ArraySegment<Byte>(a, 9, 90);

((IList<Byte>)s)[0] = 10;
Console.WriteLine(a[9]);  // writes "10"
```

So, your `Write90Bytes` method could return an `ArraySegment<Byte>` and then you could operate on that as a view into the underlying array, which would avoid the copy. Note, however, that `ArraySegment<T>` is a `System.ValueType`, which means casting it to `IList<T>` will incur a boxing penalty.

If performance is critical and you need to avoid copying, you might also consider using pointers in an unsafe context, which means your `Write90Bytes` method could return a `Byte*` and you could then index into the array that way.

**EDIT:** now that I see your edit, you can't just return a value from a function "into" the memory location of an array. You'd need to pass the original array as an argument.

**EDIT 2:** you can't do what you are asking. The `ComputeHash` function returns an array which it itself allocates. The only way you could do what you want is if `ComputeHash` took the array as a parameter. Consider:

```
// previously defined...
byte[] bigTargetBytes = new byte[10000];      

// This method doesn't really exist, but if it did it would look like this
sha256.ComputeHash(sourcebytes, bigTargetBytes, offset);
```

Although in .Net there are specific restrictions on memory allocation due to it being a managed runtime, this is a common pattern in *any* programming language. In C/C++ development, there is a protocol used where either you pass in a pre-allocated array with an offset and maxlength to write to, or you allow the function to return an allocated memory which you are then given the responsibility to free (unless you are being called back from a framework). You can't just return a value *into* an existing buffer.

Do note however, that just copying 20 bytes from a GC array allocated by the `ComputeHash` value is a very trivial operation, which the runtime handles very efficiently. Unless you are very sensitive to microsecond level pauses from time to time, you won't notice the difference between the actual copy and your hypothetical implementation.

Comment: I actually want to write to ArraySegment<Byte>.Array

Comment: This example shows that. Note the value of `a[9]` which is the original array.

Comment: I'm using `sha256.ComputeHash` and want to append its call to existing data.

Comment: You have to pass the array in, then. You could pass in an `ArraySegment<Byte>` which would allow you to skip having to pass in the offset.

Comment: I think I can do what I need if I think of my data as a struct of several byte[], and convert the struct to one big byte[].  What do you think? [I just asked this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13923360/328397)

Comment: You'll still need to copy. The reason is that the byte array isn't inlined like it appears you think it is. It's just a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you will have to make a copy either way. I suggest you to use the `Buffer.BlockCopy()` method, which is the fastest.