# How do I convert a struct to a byte array without a copy?

Tags: c#, struct, arrays, unsafe

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct struct1
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte a;   // 1 byte
    [FieldOffset(1)]
        public int b;    // 4 bytes
    [FieldOffset(5)]
        public short c;  // 2 bytes
    [FieldOffset(7)]
        public byte buffer;
    [FieldOffset(18)]
        public byte[] shaHashResult;   // 20 bytes
}

void DoStuff()
{
   struct1 myTest = new struct1();
   myTest.shaHashResult =  sha256.ComputeHash(pkBytes);  // 20 bytes

   byte[] newParameter = myTest.ToArray() //<-- How do I convert a struct 
                                          //     to array without a copy?
}
```

How do I take the array `myTest` and convert it to a byte[]?  Since my objects will be large, I don't want to copy the array (memcopy, etc)

Comment: @SLaks I found this but no corollary: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr`

Comment: If you want to avoid copying, you may want to change that to a `class`.

Comment: The byte array that you assign is just a pointer. It is not inlined.

Comment: @codekaizen has a very important point. The bytes in the shaHashResult array are not in the struct. They are somewhere out in the heap. The struct only has a reference to the array object.

Comment: Sigh... and I thought I was on a good track when I came up with using a stuct and /or Marshal

Comment: The reason this will never work is in the implementation of `ComputeHash` is a statement which is essentially `new Byte[20]`. This will always allocate a new array on the GC heap, implying a copy will need to be performed.

Comment: Here is a similar SO question discussing the issue of trying to inline an array in the struct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690382/how-can-i-put-an-array-inside-a-struct-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a big array, this is really the only way you will be able to do what you want:

```
var myBigArray = new Byte[100000];

// ...

var offset = 0;
var hash = sha256.ComputeHash(pkBytes);
Buffer.BlockCopy(myBigArray, offset, hash, 0, hash.Length);

// if you are in a loop, do something like this
offset += hash.Length;
```

This code is very efficient, and even in a tight loop, the results of `ComputeHash` will be collected in a quick Gen0 collection, while `myBigArray` will be on the Large Object Heap, and not moved or collected. The `Buffer.BlockCopy` is highly optimized in the runtime, yielding the fastest copy you could probably achieve, even in the face of pinning the target, and using an unrolled pointer copy.